# Is it possible to use css-modules classes inside markdown file?

Tags: next.js, markdown, css-modules

In my `Next.js` project , I am using `markdown-to-jsx` for my markdown files.  I want to use `css-modules` classes  for my markdown but don't know how to do it.

Inside markdown file I  have tried

```html
<p className={styles.test}>Lorem Ipsum..</p>
```

but it is not parsing and gives `class=styles.test` . I know that using `Markdown` component I can override this behaviour , but I want to be more specific.

```html
<Markdown
         options={{
           overrides:{
             p:{
               props:{
                 className:styles.test
                 
               }
             }
           }
         }}
          >
```

But doing so will affect all of the `p` tags. I want to know if it is possible to use `css-modules` inside of markdown.